# object reference not set for DataView from gridivew.DataSource as DataView

Tags: winforms, gridview, dataview, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have method validatingeditor to validate for duplicate

```
private void GridView1_ValidatingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = sender as GridView;
            DataView currentDataView = view.DataSource as DataView;
            if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Sequence")
            {
                //check duplicate code  
                string currentCode = e.Value.ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < currentDataView.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i != view.GetDataSourceRowIndex(view.FocusedRowHandle))
                    {
                        if (currentDataView[i]["Sequence"].ToString() == currentCode)
                        {
                            e.ErrorText = "Duplicate Code detected.";
                            e.Valid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it says object reference not set which the problem is at `DataView currentDataView = view.DataSource as DataView;`
But I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I was populating my gridcontrol with the ado entity dataset. so after calling `adapter.Fill(dataset)`. I also have to write `gridcontrol.DataSource=dataset;`